# Ubuntu stuck updating after restart

Tags: updates

Ubuntu 22.04 is frozen on an update screen after I selected "Restart and install updates."

The screen is just a standard "Updating, do not turn off your computer." The HDD light is not on and it has been stuck for 15 minutes now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had this and couldn't even REISUB out. Gave it the 5 second power button in the end. Seemed to reboot just fine. The log screen indicated that the updates had completed but a manual update said to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct problems.